# Change Default Size of Android Emulator in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

In the latest update of Android Studio (2.0 and above) the size of the android emulator is much smaller than it used to be when it starts up. Is there a way to change the default size to make it bigger so I don't have to always resize it after it starts up?

Answer (score 1):

In the ADV manager, you can change the startup size defining the scale, by default is "auto" but you can change to "X dp on device= Y px on screen" to size it as you prefer.