# How to change default size of android studio emulator on startup?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, avd-manager, android-studio-arctic-fox

I am not seeing the scale option in my AVD manager? I can't seem to find any way to set the default start size of the emulator? I have tried changing the screen size in editing an existing emulator also editing the resolution and nothing seems to work, I can't even find any info on this online. Let me know if anyone has found a fix!

this is the only string I can find about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36853289/change-default-size-of-android-emulator-in-android-studio-2-0/36853352#36853352?newreg=87e30c7e59674fc88f4b0b52f77f8974)